# How to limit speeds on my "Linksys Wireless-G Home Router - WRT54GH"?

Tags: wireless-networking, qos, rate-limits

I have a cable modem connected to my WRT54GH router, my main PC connected to the router with an Ethernet cable, and everyone else connected to the router via wireless.

I would like to limit download and upload speeds for each device, because I don't want people to use up all the bandwidth when uploading large pictures (or something similar).

Before this router, I was using my PC with [connectify](http://www.connectify.me) and my wireless card, so I could use something like [netlimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com) to do this, but now I need to do it on the router.

The current firmware i have on my router is: `Firmware Version: v1.0.00 build 005`

I did check [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) and [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/), but it seems that neither one supports this router.

So, what do I need to do in order to limit download and upload speeds?  Has anyone had any success with getting either firmware to work with a WRT54GH router?

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is called Quality of Service (QoS) under Applications and Gaming.

It allows you to restrict bandwidth based on different criteria (MAC address, IP address, application, physical router port).

If you are using DHCP (do your computers get IP addresses automatically?) and have people connecting wirelessly I would recommend using MAC addresses to filter out machines.  Give your computer a higher priority than the others and your issues should go away.

To find the MAC addresses of your machines (in Windows) run Command Prompt and type "ipconfig /all"

Look for the connection that maps to your router (IP address will probably be 192.168.1.xxx) and note the MAC address in the table.

edit:  I have a WRT54GL loaded with DD-WRT.  One of my motivating factors in switching to DD-WRT was the more robust QoS settings available.

Comment: Under "Applications & Gaming" i have Single Port Forwarding, Port Range Forwarding, Port Range Triggering, DMZ. If i understand correctly i need some firmware in order to get "more robust QoS settings", but i have no idea which firmware to chose.

Comment: Tomato and DD-WRT are the two most popular one.

Tomato is much more user friendly.  I hooked that up on my dad's router (he is not technical at all) and he understands it well enough to throttle the connection at our house when I'm not around.

Answer (score 4):

From the Linksys [WRT54GH FAQ](http://linksys.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/linksys.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=20529&p_created=1250752877) :

> **Q: Does the WRT54GH support wireless QOS and Internet Access Priority QOS?**
>
> A: No.

So the answer to your question is: Not possible with your current setup.

The only solution is to change the firmware, with the risk of bricking the router. Frankly, I wouldn't advice it if you describe yourself as newbie.

However, if you can find help, then you can choose between these free firmwares: [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) and [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato). Many people recommend Tomato for better QoS support.

Comment: I agree with the tomato suggestion. It seems more stable and more user friendly than DD-WRT, especially with QoS features. It's not too difficult to install, but do be careful to follow their instructions if you choose to go ahead with this. Make sure your model is supported though - I haven't heard much about the WRT54GH before. Is it a new model?

Comment: I was looking at tomato and dd-wrt before posting this question, and on both sites it seems that my model is not supported.

Comment: @GaVrA: Having studied the WRT54GH, I don't think that it supports third-party firmware. The latest firmware update (v1.0.00.005) also doesn't mention QoS. So I'm sorry to say, but the WRT54GH is just not suitable for QoS. For your next router, I suggest choosing one from the Tomato compatibility list. However, most good routers support QoS (although not at the same price-tag).

Comment: Yeah... It might seem that the best thing would be to try and sell this router and add some money and but some router that is more "third-party firmware" friendly. :)

Comment: http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/WRT54GH-Bandwith-Limiting/m-p/383191/highlight/true#M197441 Even with the 1.0.1 firmware, no QoS

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about unofficial firmware, but most routers these days have an option that levels bandwidth so each gets a fair share. With my router, if I enable "Traffic Shaping", it does that automatically.

Comment: But i dont want that "each gets a fair share". :) I want my pc to have unlimited bandwidth, while everyone else to be on some limited mode(dl and ul speed to be what i decide). Is something like this possible?

Comment: @GaVrA - Then I suggest you take a look at the dd-WRT project here: http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index If the router is relatively new, it may take some time for custom firmware to be developed.

Comment: i did find that website some time ago. The problem is that my router is "WRT54GH" and like i said, im a newbie, when i run that version through http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database i dont get any result. But when i run "WRT54G" i do find a lot of routers that are supported. I just dont know if WRT54G is the same as WRT54GH?

Comment: @GaVrA - No it is probably not... But as I said before: If the router is relatively new, it may take some time for custom firmware to be developed.

Answer (score 0):

[DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) might be able to enable this missing features on your router.