# Prevent users of the operating system from closing an active program in the background

Tags: windows-11, process, protected

I have a public computer Windows 11 is installed.

On it I have an active program on the computer that I want users to be unable to log out of.

When I say exit, I mean normal exit, through the window or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

What's important to note is that users are supposed to use this program, they just won't close it.

Comment: [If you disagree with a closure of a question you absolutely should NOT resubmit it.](https://superuser.com/questions/1820027/prevent-users-from-exiting-software) You should edit the question addressing the reasons it was closed so it can be reopened

Comment: Thank you.
 I will know how to bring it.

Comment: I ask not to be offered this link https://superuser.com/questions/1169284/is-there-a-way-to-block-guest-users-from-closing-a-certain-programI need it to not be possible to close through the software either, as I mentioned in the question, while the solution you offer me does not do that, and as the respondents mentioned there.

Comment: "They wont close it" has a totally different meaning to "Prevent users from closing it".  Which is it ?

Comment: Given the details of the question, the linked duplicate does not answer the question that was asked. OP, you need to look into Kiosk mode, which is a mode supported in Windows. Please research this and see if it solves your problem. It is a well documented feature and has been around for a long time.